# How are the Bloch equations non-linear?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-fields, terminology, non-linear-systems, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

This question is similar to the following, but I have expanded the question moderately:

[Nonlinearities arising from linear equations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/375684/nonlinearities-arising-from-linear-equations)

The Bloch equations are described by the following vector equation (ignoring relaxation):
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf{M}(t) = \mathbf{M}(t) \times \gamma \mathbf{B}(t)
$$

It is frequently stated that the Bloch equations are non-linear.

For example,

In *Principles of Magnetic Resonance Imaging - A Signal Processing Perspective* by Liang and Lauterbur (pg. 89), it is stated without elaboration that :

> The linear system assumption is not valid for a nuclear spin system during excitation.

Additionally, in *Principles of Magnetic Resonance* by Nishimura (pg. 124), it states :

> "... the nonlinear behavior of the spin system becomes appreciable."

Lastly, in *Magnetic Resonance Imaging - Physical Principles and Sequence Design* by Brown et al. (pg. 661), "Bloch equation nonlinearities" are listed as a reason for possible measurement error.

The equation listed above can be reformulated in the following manner:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\begin{bmatrix} M_x(t)\\M_y(t)\\M_z(t) \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \gamma B_z(t) & -\gamma B_y(t) \\ -\gamma B_z(t) & 0 & \gamma B_x(t) \\ \gamma B_y(t) & -\gamma B_x(t) & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} M_x(t)\\M_y(t)\\M_z(t) \end{bmatrix}
$$

This seems like a linear differential equation to me. What do people mean when they refer to the Bloch equations as non-linear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non linearities arise when you consider the feedback loop. The magnetic moment can generate a field of its own. $\mathbf{B}$ will no longer be the externally applied field, but will rather depend on $\mathbf{M}$ hence the nonlinearity. These nonlinearities give rise to new behaviors such as synchronization and chaotic motion.

Check out this article: Abergel D. "Chaotic solutions of the feedback driven Bloch equations." *Phys Lett A* 2002;302:17–22.

Hope this helps and tell me if you find some mistakes.

Comment: Thank you for the article recommendation! It sent me down a really helpful rabbit hole, and I think I understand what people mean now. So, instead of saying "the Bloch equations are non-linear." People should instead say the cumbersome, but more accurate: "the Bloch equations, as classically written, represent a linear system. However, this overlooks the interactions of the average spin magnetization on induced magnetic fields which likewise contribute to the equations of motion for these systems."

Comment: Helpful resources I encountered for future readers: Vlassenbroek et al. _J. Chem. Phys._ 103 (14) 1995.; Bowtell et al., _J. Magn. Reson._ 88. 1990.; Jeener. _Phys. Rev. Lett._ 82 (8) 1999; Krishnan and Murali. _Prog Nucl Magn Reson Spectrosc_. 68. 2013. From the last article: "In the absence of collective effects, Bloch's differential equations for the components of average spin maggnetization are linear. The presence of an induced magnetic field [...] is explictly dependent on the average spin magnetization, making these equations to be non-linear."

Answer (score 1):

First, let me note that the equations given in the OP are not the full Bloch equations, which usually include the relaxation terms with characteristic times $T_1$ and $T_2$ for the longitudinal and the transverse (in respect to the magnetic field) spin components, see [the Wikipedia article on the Bloch equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_equations).

> The linear system assumption is not valid for a nuclear spin system during excitation.

This claim does not actually imply that the equations are non-linear, but that linear response theory (e.g., in the [standard Kubo-Greenwood form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubo_formula)) cannot be used (directly) to analyze the magnetic response. Indeed, if we were to exclude two of the magnetization components, we would obtain a third-order equation with time-dependent coefficient, which is generally impossible to solve.

> "... the nonlinear behavior of the spin system becomes appreciable."

In this case one means that the magnetic field includes the field generated by the magnetic moments themselves, i.e., $\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{M})$, and the equations are thus truly non-linear. However, instead of *Bloch equation* it is more appropriate in this case to talk about the [Landau-Lifshitz-Gilbert equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%E2%80%93Lifshitz%E2%80%93Gilbert_equation).

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed and thoughtful answer! I really appreciate the high-level summary in the last paragraph. I was previously unaware of the Landau-Lifshitz-Gilbert equation.